# windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, backup, task-scheduler

We have two Windows servers. One is Windows Server 2008 and another is Windows Server 2003. We have TFS installed on Windows Server 2003 and taking daily backup on same server. I am looking to schedule a task that will move backup files from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008.

Comment: So it would be nice of you to share what you've already tried, rather than expect a magical script to appear before your very eyes. Please demonstrate you've at least thought about this for half a second and we might spare some time to help you out.

Comment: This is possible.  What is the question?

Comment: Hello Ben, Thanks for your reply. But I am looking for any magical script. I am only looking to move one file to another windows server using Windows Task Scheduler. Can you please help?

Answer (score 2):

`robocopy [source folder] [destination folder]` - bam, done.